# Error in tJava [Talend]

Tags: java, sql, talend

I'm using Talend and I've a problem which may be very silly...

The beginning of my job is :

```
tRESTRequest -> tExtractXMLFields -> tXMLMap -> tJavaRow -> tFlowToIterate -> tJava -> tFlowToIterate -> tMysqlInput ... etc
```

And i've an error on the tJava saying something like

> if you have outputs, an input link may exist to propagate data
>
> (translate from French I hope it's understandable)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here..tJavarow-->tflowtoiterate (is ok you want to iterate for each row)-->tJava-->tflowtoiterate (why this? do you explore your rows here in tJava?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more component to retrieve data from tFlowToIterate.
So add tFixedFlowInput and your sequence should be the following

tRESTRequest -> tExtractXMLFields -> tXMLMap -> tJavaRow -> tFlowToIterate -> tFixedFlowInput -> tJava

Answer (score 0):

you need use java flex component it can propagate data based on your code.  tJava is not suitable component for such operation where you need to have outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the type of the link as well.

```
Main row are used to propagate datas between components.
You need to use the Trigger -> OnSubJObOK (previously named ThenRun) link between the components.
```

Tip : Change the language of the Talend editor, it is very useful to see the translated errors (English, Portuguese, Spanish and so forth ...). After you can take advantage of these translations on forums.

cheers,